# How can I append a span only one time in selected table cell?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am developing event add calender using table. How can I append a span only one time inside the mouse dragged selected cell area and its also needs to be fluid, appended span must place in front of the selected cells. I am pasting some of my dynamic table codes here :

```
<table id="our_table">
<tr>
<th>dte1</th>
<th>dte2</th>
<th>dte3</th>
<th>dte4</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>dte1</td>
<td>dte1</td>
<td>dte1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your question is really not clear.  What do you want exactly?

Comment: Why dont you put your `<th></th>` within `<thead></thead>` and the data of table in `<tbody></tbody>`

Comment: I need to append a span only one time in selected table cells (means- if i selected 3 cells then i need to merge the cells and append a span into it, and also when i clicked the remove button then the span needs to deleted and the cells must be unmerged. is this possible plzz needs ur help

Comment: Can you show a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what have you tried.

Comment: sorry for that,there is a lots of codes in my work. can u tell how to merge selected table cells on click event